# lookAt for child object

Tags: three.js

Trying to make a CHILD of an object look at a position (which is in global/world space)

Here's what I've got, but it doesn't work.
Direction of arrow seems to roam around in unpredictable directions.

**Update** (added example): https://jsfiddle.net/um8cxp3b/27/

```js
makeArrowLookAt(obj, position) {
 
  // obj.lookAt(position); // works PERFECTLY, but I want a child object to lookAt...
      
  const posVector = new THREE.Vector3().copy(position); // copy
  const localVector = obj.worldToLocal(posVector); // get local position offset
  localVector.normalize(); // converts local offset to rotation... right?
      
  // Apply the localised rotation to the object
  obj.children[0].rotation.x = localVector.x;
  obj.children[0].rotation.y = localVector.y;
  obj.children[0].rotation.z = localVector.z;
}
```

(Note the child in this case is an arrowHelper to illustrate direction)

Answer (score 1):

`lookAt()` does support transformed ancestors (assuming they are not non-uniformly-scaled). So it should be just:

```js
obj.children[0].lookAt(position);
```

Assuming `position` is the target position in world space.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried... this makes the arrow point in a consistent direction, but not the correct direction (causes arrow to stare at different unrelated direction)

Comment: Do you mind sharing a live example that shows what you are doing? https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: Not at all! https://jsfiddle.net/um8cxp3b/27/ (thanks for fork project, that saved me a lot of googling!) I'll update question to include fiddle example as well